# Chain crashing with `SinkImpl::poll_ready called after error.`

Tags: libp2p

Experiencing panic in `libp2p-websocket` with logs looking like

```
Thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'SinkImpl::poll_ready called after error.'
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed - https://github.com/libp2p/rust-yamux/pull/138

Now [tagged and published](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-yamux/pull/138#issuecomment-1206103021) - [yamux 0.10.2](https://crates.io/crates/yamux/0.10.2)

To apply this fix just a quick `cargo update -p yamux` is needed to apply the latest yamux version.

Comment: Is it the same when you use a docker?

Comment: This only has to do with the version of yamux being used, not with how the nodes are being deployed. So, it will pop up independently of the way nodes are being deployed while the yamux version being used is the one not patched.

Comment: However, yamux and cargo were not found in the docker image. Can you give me a guide to update yamux simply for Docker users?